# php escape characters, replacing string content with image source tag

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php echo anchor($this->lang->switch_uri($switchLang), "switch language" ?>
```

I want to replace this switch language message with country flag.

how can I escape characters and display img src inside that string message

```
<?php echo anchor($this->lang->switch_uri($switchLang), "<img src='/somepath.jpg')"; ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo anchor($this->lang->switch_uri($switchLang), "<img src=\'/somepath.jpg\'"); ?>
```

1. Moved the trailing double quotes inside the bracket
2. Added escape slashes to the single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
echo str_replace("switch language","<img src='/somepath.jpg' />","Your string ")
```